# Why is each component of a random vector a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am reading A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by Dragi Anevski and in chapter 5 about random vectors, he proves that each component of a random vector is a random variable. Unfortunately, I need some help with comprehending the authors proof:

"Suppose that $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a probability space and $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random vector. We assume $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a random vector and want to show that for any $1 \leq i \leq n$, $X_i$is a random variable. This follows since for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x\} = \{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x\} \cap \Omega = \{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x\} \cap (\cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}) = \{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x,\cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}\}$$. And since this is in the sigma algebra, $F$, $X_i$ is a random variable.".

What I don't understand is the reformulation $\Omega = \cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}$. Are you supposed to read it as 'the outcome space is equal to the intersection of all events that each $X_j$ for $j \neq i \in \{1,..,n\}$ gives rise to as $x \to \infty$'? Why is it an intersection and not a union?

I have not yet read about measure theory and looking at other answers it seems measure theory is a prerequisite.

I also dont understand the conclusion: why $$\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x,\cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}\} \in F$$.

I tried looking for an answer on the internet, on this website. Didn't find any other proof of it and has been searching for over two hours now.

Thank you in advance, 
Isak

Comment: The last set is $X^{-1}((-\infty,x]\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$. Since $(-\infty,x]\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is Borel and $X$ is a random variable then $X^{-1}((-\infty,x]\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1})\in F$. You can read $X^{-1}((-\infty,x]\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ as, the first component is not greater than $x$, while the others take any value, which is the same as just saying, the first component is not larger than $x$.

Comment: More (tediously) precisely: $$X_i^{-1}((-\infty,x])=X^{-1}(\mathbb R^{i-1}\times(-\infty,x]\times\mathbb R^{n-i})$$

Comment: I just went over the arguments one more time, and I couldn’t help but to think that in the first equality in the proof imply that $A=\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x \} \subseteq \Omega$. And since $\Omega \in F$ this implies that $A \in F$? I mean, isn’t it wrong to assume that from the beginning when that is in fact what we want to show?

Comment: That would be wrong, but it does not happen.

Comment: Ok. Where does my logic steer off?

Comment: "..And since $\Omega\in F$ this implies that $A\in F$.." that would be wrong to conclude, and you seem to think that this conclusion is made. However that conclusion is not made. If you still believe it is made then please point me out exactly where it is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct proof is as follows:
$$
X_i(\omega) \le x_i \Leftrightarrow (X_1(\omega), \dots, X_n(\omega)) \in \{(t_1, \dots, t_n) : t_i \le x_i\} =: B.
$$ 
Therefore,
$$
\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \le x_i\} = \{\omega : (X_1(\omega), \dots, X_n(\omega)) \in B\}.
$$
Since $B$ is a Borel set, the above set belongs to F. Contrary to what the book says, one has to be familiar with measure theory to understand this.

To be precise, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open sets. It is also the smallest one containing all closed sets. Since $B$ is closed, it is a Borel set.

Also, at Jul 25 at 12:19 you asked if $A \subseteq \Omega$ and $\Omega \in F$ implies $A \in F$. The answer is no, since $A$ and $\Omega$ are sets of outcomes of some experiment, while $F$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$, namely those to which probability is assigned. In this case $A$ happened to belong to $F$, but that had to be proved.

In my opinion, this book is not suitable for a first course in probability; your university library might help you to find some complement.

Don´t despair

Bengt

Sorry, the above pertains to an alternative definition mentioned in a footnote. The one used in the book is:

$(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is a random vector if $\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \le x_j,\,  j = 1, \dots, n \} \in F$ for all real numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Now, the proof is
$$
\{\omega : X_1(\omega) \le x_1\} \\
=\{\omega : X_1(\omega) \le x_1, X_j(\omega) < \infty, \,j = 2, \dots, n\}\\
= \cup_{k=1}^\infty
\{\omega : X_1(\omega) \le x_1, X_j(\omega) \le k, \,j = 2, \dots,n\} \in F,
$$
since all sets in the union belong to $F$, and $F$ is a sigma-algebra.

Bengt

Answer (score 0):

If $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is a random vector then sets of the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leq x_i\}$ for $x_i\in(-\infty,\infty]$ are measurable.

This fact can be used to prove that e.g. $X_1$ is a random variable.

This because the set $\{X_1\leq x\}$ is exactly the same as the set $\{X_1\leq x, X_2\leq\infty,\dots, X_n\leq\infty\}$

so appears to be measurable if $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is a random vector.

The last set can also be denoted as: $\{X_1\leq x\}\cap(\bigcap_{i=2}^n\{X_i\leq\infty\})$

or as $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leq x_i\}$ where $x_1=x$ and $x_i=\infty$ if $i\neq 1$.

The "conclusion" $$\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x,\cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}\} \in F$$

makes no sense to me.

My conclusion is that $\{\omega:X_1(\omega)\leq x\}\in F$

Comment: Thank you, your third line cleared up a lot of confusion but I am still confused about why the outcome space $\Omega$ can be written as that intersection. Is it because it is assumed that each $X_i$ is a function mapping from the same outcome space?

Comment: Let $\omega$ be an arbitrary element of $\Omega$. For every $j\neq i$ we have $X_j(\omega)\leq\infty$, or equivalently $\omega\in\{X_j\leq\infty\}$. So we are justified to conclude that $\omega\in\bigcap_{j\neq i}\{X_j\leq\infty\}$. So *every* element of $\Omega$ is an element of $\bigcap_{j\neq i}\{X_j\leq\infty\}\subseteq\Omega$.

Comment: I agree about the "conclusion" stated in the book. The "set" notation $\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x,\cap_{j \neq i}\{\omega : X_j(\omega) \leq \infty\}\}$ seems ill-formed to me. Perhaps they meant $\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x, X_1(\omega) \leq \infty, \ldots, X_{i-1}(\omega) \leq \infty, X_{i+1}(\omega) \leq \infty, \ldots, X_n(\omega) \leq \infty\}.$

Comment: I just went over the arguments one more time, and I couldn’t help but to think that in the first equality in the proof imply that $A=\{\omega : X_i(\omega) \leq x \} \subseteq \Omega$. And since $\Omega \in F$ this implies that $A \in F$? I mean, isn’t it wrong to assume that from the beginning when that is in fact what we want to show?

Comment: $A_1=\{X_1\leq x\}\subseteq\Omega\in F$ but the conclusion that $A_1\in F$ is not based on that. For that it is used that $A_1=\{X_1\leq x\}=\{X_1\leq x,X_2\leq\infty,\dots,X_n\leq\infty\}$. The set on RHS must be an element of $F$ because $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is a random vector.